# How can I redirect all users via a single page based on admin rights?

Tags: php, authentication, redirect

I'm trying to set up a login for website, where a user can have one of three states. I have this set in a connected file called 'authenticate.php' which on login checks my DB for the value "version" where the values can be 1,2 or 3 depending on access level. This file is then set up to redirect set up to one of three different pages, for instance home1.php, home2.php, home3.php. I am happy with having 3 separate pages, as I want this control.

In the same directory as these files, there is a folder of content which users will only be able to see some of the pages from. For example:

- website (FOLDER)

  - authenticate.php
  - index.html
  - home1.php
  - home2.php
  - home3.php
  - content (FOLDER)

    - news1.html
    - news2.html
    - news3.html

The problem is, that with my current implementation, when the user is on any one of these content pages, I can't link them back to the right version of the home page they're meant to be seeing.

As a solution, I was thinking of using a new file 'home.php' to always direct to, and then redirect the user to where they need to go, as opposed to dealing with all of this in the authentication.php file like I'm doing currently. This would allow me to send the user to home.php, and then they'd be redirected to the version they're meant to see.

I have used what's happening in the original authenticate.php and I have tried replicating the check to the DB to get the value of "version", but this doesn't seem to be working. As I'm sure is obvious from my code, I am not experienced in PHP I am also unsure whether it's necessary to reconnect to the DB once this has already been made in the session.

Any help would be really appreciated, as I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

Thank you!

Code:

**Authenticate.php**

```
session_start();
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'john'
$DATABASE_PASS = 'password';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'users';

$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
        exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {
    exit('Please fill both the username and password fields!');
}

if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
        $stmt->fetch();

        if ($_POST['password'] === $password) {
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            header('Location: home.php');
        } else {
            echo 'Incorrect username and/or password!';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect username and/or password!';
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
```

**Home.php**

```
<?php

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['version'] == 1 )) {
  header('Location: home1.php');
    exit;
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['version'] == 2 )) {
    header('Location: home2.php');
      exit;
  }

  if (!isset($_SESSION['version'] == 3 )) {
    header('Location:home3.php');
      exit;
  }
```

Comment: Is the user's session set properly after their authentication? It sounds like you are posing an authorization question, meaning the user is able to login but do they have access? Would you please add log output, like `var_dump` the session to see if the user's session is set properly. It appears the line `if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {` is an assignment which may always be true. This would be a situation where it is basically meaningless and will always execute what is within the if block.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've managed to get an output of what's being captured in the Session, and it looks like version isn't being stored. It is storing loggedin, id, and username.

Comment: It looks like you have `session_start` on all pages but that is another possible cause of errors. Also, please be sure to have both client and server-side validation. Without it there are serious security concerns. For PHP be sure to check out https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php